# A fact about symmetric matrices and square roots

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Is it true that if $A$ is symmetric then any square root is symmetric? I can't prove this using basic symbolic computation, so what if we insist that $A$ is diagonalizable, or even positive definite?

Comment: Square root of what?

Comment: $\sqrt A$ $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general. For example:
$$\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}^2 = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1} .$$
Note that the matrix on the l.h.s. is diagonalizable (over $\Bbb C$).

Comment: What if $A$ was positive definite? What could we conclude? I'm trying to find conditions under which this could hold, and positive definiteness is fine.

Comment: Even that doesn't hold; $I$ is symmetric and positive definite but has many [non-symmetric square roots](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806853/how-to-find-an-upper-triangular-with-u2-i-which-gives-u-is-its-own?noredirect=1#comment3691493_1806853)

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, it admits a unique positive semidefinite square root, and that square root is necessarily symmetric.